# Strict linear order on the connected compact with only two non-breaking points

Tags: general-topology

$X$ is a compact, Hausdorff and connected space.
It has only two points $a$ and $b$ such that $X \setminus \{a\}$, $X \setminus \{b\}$ are connected, they are called non-breaking.
Then for every point $x \in X \setminus \{a, b\}$: $X \setminus \{x\}$ is not connected, that means $ X \setminus \{x\} = A(x) \cup B(x)$, where $a \in A(x)$, $b \in B(x)$, $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are open, not empty and $A(x) \cap B(x) = \varnothing$.
We introduce the strict order: $x \lt y$ if $A(x) \subset A(y)$.

How can I prove that this order is linear, that every two points of $X$ are comparable?
I've tried to prove by contradiction with the fact that $X$ is connected, but hadn't succeded.

Also we know that $A(x) \cup \{x\}$ is connected compact and there are at least two non-breaking points for every connected compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x,y\in X\backslash \{a,b\}$,  $x\neq y$. Then either $y\in A(x)$ or $y\in B(x)$.

If $y\in A(x)$, then $B(x)\cup \{x\}$ is a connected subset of $X\backslash\{y\}$.  Since it is connected, it is either contained in or disjoint from any given clopen subset of $X\backslash \{y\}$.

In particular, since $B(y)$ is clopen in $X\backslash \{y\}$ and $b\in B(y)\cap (B(x)\cup\{x\})$, we must have $B(x)\cup\{x\} \subseteq B(y)$, whereby $A(x)\supseteq A(y)\cup\{y\}$, and since $y\in A(x)\backslash A(y)$, we have a proper inclusion $A(y)\subset A(x)$.

Similarly, if $y\in B(x)$, then $A(x)\cup\{x\}$ is a connected subset of $X\backslash\{y\}$, and so must be contained in or disjoint from $A(y)$.  Since $a\in (A(x)\cup\{x\})\cap A(y)$, we have $A(x)\cup\{x\}\subseteq A(y)$, and since $x\in A(y)\backslash A(x)$, we get the proper inclusion $A(x)\subset A(y)$.